# Android studio 3.0 Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

After upgrading from version 2.7 preview 7  to 3.0 even on every new project create getting this error

Error: Failed to open the zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

As I think when the project is creating .gradle folder is created in the directory. but in my case after upgrading it's not creating. have any idea
thanks in advance

#### Screen Shots:

[image: app module gradle]
[image: Project gradle with error]

Comment: Try deleting the settings of the Android Studio by removing the directory %HOMEPATH%\.AndroidStudioPreview3.0

Comment: Did you try clicking on "Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)"? That might fix the problem.

Comment: @Naetmul Already done but not succeeded.as i said .gradle folder is not creating

Comment: @Rams its not  worked a tried it alot :P

Comment: Did you try this: File --> Invalidate cache and Restart?

Comment: @Rams yes .also not worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I Got solution . As i checked in my sample project all thing are settled .Only the issue is slow internet which is not able to download gradle. So i manually download it and i have to change it from (Default which i don't want)to local.
[image]

Comment: From where did you download Gradle?

Comment: @Isuru here is a [repository](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)